# Where clause with like and not like operators not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT 
REPLACE(REPLACE(A.[NOME COMERCIAL],'.',''),'&','') AS [NOME COMERCIAL]        ,
ISNULL(A.[PLANO], '') AS PLANO       ,
A.[Plano Foco]        ,
CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),A.[PRECO]) AS PRECO        ,
B.[FEAT_CAMERA]        ,
B.[FEAT_TELA]        ,
B.[FEAT_CAP_ARMAZENAMENTO]        ,
B.[FEAT_PROCESSADOR]        ,
B.[FEAT_MEMORIA_RAM]        ,
B.[FEAT_BATERIA]        ,
B.[EXTRA_INFO_1]        ,
B.[EXTRA_INFO_2]        ,
B.[EXTRA_INFO_3]  
FROM [TABELA DE PRECOS] AS A
LEFT JOIN DE_PARA_SAP_APARELHOS AS B
  ON (A.[NOME DPGC] = B.APARELHODPAV)
WHERE PLANO LIKE '%CONTROLE%'
  AND PLANO NOT LIKE '%Renova%'
  AND A.[PRODUTO] IN ('Smartphone', 'Blackbox 3G', 'Blackbox 4G', 'Fixo', 'Modem 3G', 'Modem 4G', 'Tablet')
  AND REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(A.[NOME DPGC],'&',''),'''',''),'.','') = 'Iphone XR 64GB' 
   OR REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(B.[APARELHODPAV],'&',''),'''',''),'.','') = 'Iphone XR 64GB'
  AND A.[REGIAO] = '7x'
ORDER BY PRECO,[PLANO]
```

I've searched a bit and found that if you have null values, LIKE and NOT LIKE could not work properly, so i'm using ISNULL. But i'm still getting values that contains 'Renova':

```
Novo Vivo V (Renova)
Novo Vivo V
Vivo Família 70GB (Renova)
Vivo Família 50GB (Renova)
Vivo Família 70GB
Vivo Controle....
```

I don't get any error messages. The query runs fine, but it's like my like and not like operators are being ignored or something like that. What am i missing here?

Comment: It's not the `(NOT) LIKE`. When you format your query (I did it for you) it's easier to spot that there's an `OR`ed condition. `AND` has a higher precedence than `OR`, you probably don't want that --> add parens around the `OR`ed condition. `AND (REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(A.[NOME DPGC],'&',''),'''',''),'.','') 
    = 'Iphone XR 64GB' 
   OR REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(B.[APARELHODPAV],'&',''),'''',''),'.','') 
    = 'Iphone XR 64GB')  AND A.[REGIAO] = '7x'`. Btw, you should **always** use parens when you mix `AND` and `OR`

Comment: @dnoeth dont know why you didnt make it an answer

Comment: `LIKE and NOT LIKE could not work properly, so i'm using ISNULL` ..... I dont see ISNULL anywhere

Answer (score 0):

brackets missing on OR clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(REPLACE(A.[NOME COMERCIAL],'.',''),'&','') AS [NOME COMERCIAL]        ,
                ISNULL(A.[PLANO], '') AS PLANO       ,
                A.[Plano Foco]        ,
                CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),A.[PRECO]) AS PRECO        ,
                B.[FEAT_CAMERA]        ,
                B.[FEAT_TELA]        ,
                B.[FEAT_CAP_ARMAZENAMENTO]        ,
                B.[FEAT_PROCESSADOR]        ,
                B.[FEAT_MEMORIA_RAM]        ,
                B.[FEAT_BATERIA]        ,
                B.[EXTRA_INFO_1]        ,
                B.[EXTRA_INFO_2]        ,
                B.[EXTRA_INFO_3]  
FROM @A AS A 
    LEFT JOIN @B AS B  ON 
    A.[NOME DPGC] = B.APARELHODPAV
WHERE   PLANO LIKE '%CONTROLE%'  AND 
        PLANO NOT LIKE '%Renova%'  AND 
        A.[PRODUTO] IN ('Smartphone', 'Blackbox 3G', 'Blackbox 4G', 'Fixo', 'Modem 3G', 'Modem 4G', 'Tablet')  AND 
        (REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(A.[NOME DPGC],'&',''),'''',''),'.','') = 'Iphone XR 64GB' OR REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(B.[APARELHODPAV],'&',''),'''',''),'.','') = 'Iphone XR 64GB') AND 
        A.[REGIAO] = '7x' 
ORDER BY PRECO,[PLANO]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you do not want to include Renova, do not include it in your where clause and it will be exempted from the selection. That will solve your problem.